# SQL query update by grouping

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm dealing with some legacy data in an Oracle table and have the following

```
--------------------------------------------
| RefNo                         |     ID   |                          
--------------------------------------------
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/AAAAAAAAAA        |      1   |
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/BBBBBBBBBB        |      1   |
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/CCCCCCCCCC        |      1   |
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/DDDDDDDDDD        |      1   |
--------------------------------------------
```

For each of the /FOO/BAR/BAZ/% records I want to make the ID a Unique incrementing number.
Is there a method to do this in SQL?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Sorry for not being specific. I have several groups of records /FOO/BAR/BAZ/, /FOO/ZZZ/YYY/. The same transformation needs to occur for each of these other (example) groups. The recnum can't be used I want ID to start from 1, incrementing, for each group of records I have to change.

Sorry for making a mess of my first post. Output should be

```
--------------------------------------------
| RefNo                         |     ID   |                          
--------------------------------------------
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/AAAAAAAAAA        |      1   |
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/BBBBBBBBBB        |      2   |
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/CCCCCCCCCC        |      3   |
| FOO/BAR/BAZ/DDDDDDDDDD        |      4   |
| FOO/ZZZ/YYY/AAAAAAAAAA        |      1   |
| FOO/ZZZ/YYY/BBBBBBBBBB        |      2   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Avalanche:Can RefNo be duplicate ? and if yes then do you want both the duplicate Refno having same ID or different Unique id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try something like this(Oracle version 10g and higher):

```
SQL> with t1 as(
  2    select 'FOO/BAR/BAZ/AAAAAAAAAA' as RefNo,  1 as ID from dual union all
  3    select 'FOO/BAR/BAZ/BBBBBBBBBB',  1 from dual union all
  4    select 'FOO/BAR/BAZ/CCCCCCCCCC',  1 from dual union all
  5    select 'FOO/BAR/BAZ/DDDDDDDDDD',  1 from dual union all
  6    select 'FOO/ZZZ/YYY/AAAAAAAAAA',  1 from dual union all
  7    select 'FOO/ZZZ/YYY/BBBBBBBBBB',  1 from dual union all
  8    select 'FOO/ZZZ/YYY/CCCCCCCCCC',  1 from dual union all
  9    select 'FOO/ZZZ/YYY/DDDDDDDDDD',  1 from dual
 10  )
 11  select row_number() over(partition by ComPart order by DifPart) as id
 12       , RefNo
 13     From (select regexp_substr(RefNo, '[[:alpha:]]+$')   as DifPart
 14                , regexp_substr(RefNo, '([[:alpha:]]+/)+') as ComPart
 15                , RefNo
 16                , Id
 17             from t1
 18           ) q
 19  ;

        ID REFNO
---------- -----------------------
         1 FOO/BAR/BAZ/AAAAAAAAAA
         2 FOO/BAR/BAZ/BBBBBBBBBB
         3 FOO/BAR/BAZ/CCCCCCCCCC
         4 FOO/BAR/BAZ/DDDDDDDDDD
         1 FOO/ZZZ/YYY/AAAAAAAAAA
         2 FOO/ZZZ/YYY/BBBBBBBBBB
         3 FOO/ZZZ/YYY/CCCCCCCCCC
         4 FOO/ZZZ/YYY/DDDDDDDDDD
```

I think that actual updating the `ID` column wouldn't be a good idea. Every time you add new groups of data you would have to run the update statement again. The better way would be creating a view and you will see desired output every time you query it.

Comment: runnning this on 10G I get "with t1(RefNo, ID) as(" error at line 1: ORA-32033: unsupported column aliasing.

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche Sorry, that is right because 10g doesn't support column aliasing in the `with` clause of a query. I've updated the answer. `With` part of the query contains sample of data from your question. You can take just a query(change the table name in the from clause from `t1` to you table name) and try it on your data.

Comment: Ideal. Is there a way to alter the query to run against column names from the actual table?

Answer (score 1):

rownum can be used as an incrementing ID?

```
UPDATE legacy_table
    SET id = ROWNUM;
```

This will assign unique values to all records in the table.  [This link contains documentation about Oracle Pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm).

Comment: Sorry for not being specific, I'll update the question above. There are other records in the table I wish to update

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following:

```
update <table_name> set id = rownum where descr like 'FOO/BAR/BAZ/%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty rough and I'm not sure if your RefNo is a single value column or you just made it like that for simplicity.

```
select 
    sub.RefNo
    row_number() over (order by sub.RefNo) + (select max(id) from TABLE),

from (
    select FOO+'/'+BAR+'/'+BAZ+'/'+OTHER as RefNo
    from TABLE
    group by FOO+'/'+BAR+'/'+BAZ+'/'+OTHER
) sub
```